# Subshell and signal propagation

Tags: subshell, trap

I am curious about signal propagation in subshells. I have the following bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function test_trap() {
   echo "hello"
}
trap 'test_trap' SIGUSR2

(#subshell
trap 'test_trap' SIGUSR2
some_command
)
other commands
```

which I then submit to the grid using the SGE grid engine. Trouble is, when I cancel the job, SGE sends the SIGUSR2 signal to it and then after a preconfigured amount of time (or if the script doesn't handle the signal or already handled it) sends a SIGKILL.

My problem is that somehow, the signal doesn't reach the command within the subshell. However, if I add a simple `sleep 1` command to the trap then the signal is correctly propagated. It could be the SGE issue, however, just wanted to be sure I am not doing anything silly within the bash script itself.